# Is there a reputation threshold for including pictures in questions (and answers)?

Tags: feature-request, new-users, images, privileges

I am currently [interacting with a new user who has a question I think is interesting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164677/prediction-intervals-for-forecasts-using-spectral-analysis?noredirect=1#comment313278_164677). To move the discussion forward, he really needs to show a picture. Unfortunately, he can't do that yet.

Somewhat surprisingly, I didn't find the reputation threshold for including pictures in questions (or answers) in the [list of privileges](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). Nor did searches on [meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=include+picture+in+question) or [meta.CV](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=include+picture+in+question) yield anything particularly helpful.

I have two factual questions and one question I'd like to discuss. The factual questions are:

1. What's the reputation (or other) threshold for being able to include pictures in questions?
2. What's the reputation (or other) threshold for being able to include pictures in answers?

(Maybe the site admins could include this info in the [list of privileges](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).)

---

The question I'd like to get y'all's opinion on is:

> Does this reputation threshold for including pictures make sense for CV?

It seems to me like there are far more questions that would profit from pictures on CV than on many other SE sites. So keeping new users from posting pictures raises a higher hurdle for them on CV than on, say, [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/), or [Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/), or [Workplace.SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), where you will rarely-if-ever see a picture.

Consequently, I'd propose allowing new users to include pictures in questions and answers on CV, or reduce the rep threshold (maybe to 5, so the first upvoter could ask them to edit the question and include the picture).

Thoughts?

Comment: According to http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258876 (see also linked answers), the reputation threshold for including pictures is 10, but only on several large SE sites such as e.g. SO and Math; on other SE sites including CV there should be no threshold. It would be good to confirm if this is really true for CV though.

Comment: In the past, we've been quite happy to put an image in the post if posters include a link to the image (they're easy to upload to imgur, but any non-dodgy site where you can access the image directly would do). But I haven't had to do that for someone for a long time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a test, I just included an image in an answer with a new account:

[image]

As you see, you only need 1 reputation -- which everyone gets -- to do that. (Since it's a useless answer, I also deleted it.)

I haven't tested posting questions at this point (I hesitate to spam the site with tests). I'll try to find out for sure whether the limit applies to questions, but it would seem odd to allow a rep 1 user to use images in answers but not questions.

(Taking whuber's comment as encouragement to do so, I'll expand on my earlier comment:)

---

In any case, in the past, we've (as in 'we active users') been quite happy to put an image in the post if posters include a link to the image (they're easy to upload to imgur, but any non-dodgy site where you can access the image directly would do). While I haven't had to do that for someone for a long time, I'd be happy to do it any time I saw that it was needed; if a user with sufficient reputation to do so didn't take care of it already (as often happens), a flag would suffice to alert a moderator to the need.

Helping a new user who is taking the trouble to illustrate an aspect of their question is a reasonably pleasant task and it's not like we're overwhelmed with such requests at the moment.

Comment: +1. Nevertheless, your comment to the question perhaps is even a more constructive answer: when a newbie encounters difficulties posting an image (for whatever reason) but otherwise appears to have a good question, it takes little time or effort to have them provide a link to the image and then for us (anybody) to convert that link to one that is supported by the SE engine.